# connection string issue after hosting website

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, web, hosting

Please help me with this!
I've put my website on somee.com, they gave this connection string

```
Connection string:  workstation id=GWAPDataBase.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=xxxx;pwd=xxxxx;data source=GWAPDataBase.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=GWAPDataBase
```

and my auto generated connection string when i was on local host was

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="GWAP_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.GWAPModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.GWAPModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.GWAPModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I tried to modify it, but I get an error that says

> The specified named connection is either not found in the
> configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
> or not valid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The specified named
> connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to
> be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 19:     #region Constructors Line 20:  Line 21:     public
> GWAP_Entities() Line 22:         : base(ConnectionString,
> ContainerName) Line 23:     {

Please help me how should I modify the connection string?

Comment: You may not wish to give out the domain, username and password for your database box.  Just saying.

Comment: FYI: make sure those aren't your actual username and pw for your connection string.

Comment: Change your password _right now_

Comment: Thanks for advice, but can any one help me, I need this so much

Comment: What did your connection string look like that generated the error?

Comment: I replaced my auto generated connection string with the one they told me, and didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your connection string name and the name that the Entity Framework expects do not match.  Without more information about how your code looks, I am assuming that you generated your models from the database using the wizard in Visual Studio.  When you do that, you enter a name for the connection string which then gets hard-coded in your designer file.  An example:

```
public FooEntity() : base("name=FooEntity", "FooEntity")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

The string "FooEntity" in this case would need to be the name of the connection string.  If they are different, a connection string won't be found.  Make sure those values match.

Comment: They match,I tried now to put the connection string like this :
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
<add
name="ApplicationServices"
connectionString="Data Source=GWAPDataBase.mssql.somee.com;
Initial Catalog=GWAPDataBase;
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=xxxx;
Password=xxxxx" />
<add
name="GWAP_Entities"
connectionString="Data Source=GWAPDataBase.mssql.somee.com;
Initial Catalog=GWAPDataBase;
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=xxxxx;
Password=xxxxx"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


but also didn't word

Comment: Can you post the code of the constructor methods of your designer files?

Comment: public const string ConnectionString = "name=GWAP_Entities";
    public const string ContainerName = "GWAP_Entities";
    public GWAP_Entities()
        : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public GWAP_Entities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public GWAP_Entities(EntityConnection connection)
        : base(connection, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }